# Find a directory in a list of directories containing a portion of a string using python

Tags: python, windows, search, directory, subdirectory

My first post and I'm rather new to programming so please be patient with me. I've searched quite a bit for somebody else trying to solve this problem but I can't find a specific case like mine.

If I have a directory with a bunch of subdirectories, and I want to find a specific directory who's name contains a portion of the text I'm looking for, I want to be able to move that directory to another directory.

So for example, I have the following directories

- c:/users/bob/folders/folder123
- c:/users/bob/folders/folder456
- c:/users/bob/folders/folder789
- c:/users/bob/folders/folder0

I ask the user "What string are you looking for?". Let's imagine the user tells me that they're looking for the string "123". I want to be able to find a folder that contains that text and then move that folder and all of its contents to a new directory.

Getting the input from the user is obviously quite easy

```
print('What is the rev number?') #ask the user for the rev number
revNumber = input()
```

Now I need to pass that variable into some code that searches a specific directory for folders containing that text. Once the folder is found, how do I move it? I know how to move individual files using shutil.move and was wondering if it could also be used to move an entire folder and all of its contents.

Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `os` package to create directories and then copying the content with shutil. Note that with os you have functions to traverse entire directory hierarchies with "walk()". Have a look at the documentation.

Shutil can also move directories, though.

Then to search for a particular string in another string, you can use the "in" keywords that returns true if the string was found:

```
# Example path
path = path/to/folder/file6854.jpg

# String to look for
to_find = "854"

if to_find in path:
  # Do something
```

Comment: Thanks @Louis

While waiting for a response I just did a ton of work to try to figure this out and came across the os.scandir function (method?) which accomplished creating a list and scanning the directory for folders. I then used your same technique to search for the specific string in the list. I was also able to use the shutil.move function to move the folder I wanted. Now I'm just trying to figure out how to move it to a specific subdirectory. Programming's hard lol